# JSF use of ui:repeat varStatus.index as an array index

Tags: jsf, mojarra

This code works in Jakarta Faces 2.3.14, but fails in 2.3.15 and 2.3.16:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="fid" value="#{myForm}" converter="#{formsConverter}" />
  <f:viewAction action="#{myForm.init}" />
</f:metadata>
...

<ui:repeat var="q" value="#{myForm.questions}" varStatus="stat">
      <tr><td>#{stat.index+1}.</td>
        <td><h:outputText value="#{q}" /></td>
        <td><h:selectOneRadio group="q#{stat.index}" value="#{myForm.answers[stat.index]}" 
 required="true" label="Question #{stat.index}" >
      <f:selectItem itemValue="1" />
...
```

The part that fails is `value="#{myForm.answers[stat.index]}"`.  When I try to submit the form in Jakarta Faces 2.3.15, it throws the following exception:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [] threw exception [/forms/myform.xhtml @43,117 value="#{myForm.answers[stat.index]}": Target Unreachable, [null] returned null] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, [null] returned null
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:119)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:58)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:174)
...
```

I've tried initializing `answers` in both @PostConstruct and also a viewAction, but still get the same error. If I access `answers` using a hard-coded number, e.g. `answers[0]`, there is no error. The error only occurs with `answers[stat.index]`

I'm wondering if this is a regression or if the spec doesn't allow the use of varStatus.index as an array index, in which case I need to find a new way of doing it.

Bean code:

```
@Named @ViewScoped
public class MyForm {
  protected String[] answers = new String[42];

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    answers = new String[42];
    Arrays.fill(answers, "");
  }

...
}
```

#### Update

I worked around this by using `<c:forEach />` instead of `<ui:repeat />`, but it still seems like a bug given that `<ui:repeat />` works in 2.3.14.

Comment: @JasperdeVries I can't find anything in that answer that applies - the closest thing is making sure the referenced entity is not null - I'm setting `answers` in both the constructor and also a @PostConstruct, so I don't see how it can be null. And it works fine in 2.3.14, which is why I'm confused.

Comment: Might be worth reporting. If you could include a [mcve] with the issue that would be helpful. https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues

Comment: @JasperdeVries Will do - thanks for the link to report this.